# update table2 by getting value from table1

Tags: sql, oracle

My questions is that I have 3 tables and **table2 must be updated comparing table1** which **table1 code must be in table3**.

[image]

```
update table2 s 
set s.code=
   (select t.code
      from table1 t
     where s.sum = t.sum
       and s.number= t.number
       and t.code in (select pcode from table3))
```

This is what i have. But this code didn't work. Thanks to all answers.

Comment: "didn't work" is not helpful for fixing a problem.

Comment: what is your advice, to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Your subquery can return more than one row -- at least nothing in the *SQL* prevents that, although the data might happen to not have duplicates.  If your problem are duplicates, you can remove the error by doing:

```
set s.code = (
        select t.code
        from table1 t
        where s.sum = t.sum and
              s.number= t.number and
              t.code in (select pcode from table3) and
              rownum = 1
       )
```

Note that this would get rid of the problem by assigning an *arbitrary* matching code.  That may or may not be what you want.

Comment: In this code will table2 be updated matching requirements because requirement is inside of scope. 
So it is taking long table

Comment: I am not sure my code is correct it was for explanation

Answer (score 0):

This is the code worked fine.

```
update table2 s
   set s.code=
   (select code
      from tabe1 t
     where t.sum= s.sum
       and t.number= s.number
       and t.code in ('4003413',
                   '4001366',
                   '4001461',
                   '4003046',
                   '4001414'))
 where exists (select 1
      from table1 t
     where t.sum= s.sum
       and t.number= s.number
       and t.code in ('4003413',
                   '4001366',
                   '4001461',
                   '4003046',
                   '4001414'));
```